# Does the property ${n\choose r}={n\choose n-r}$ have a name?

Tags: terminology, binomial-coefficients

Due to the relation between Pascal's Triangle and the *choose* function in probability theory, we can deduce that $${n\choose r}={n\choose n-r}$$
because Pascal's Triangle is symmetric. This can also be verified algebraically. It's the reason why, for example, if we choose 4 children then the remaining 6 out of a class of 10, the order in which we do it doesn't matter ($^{10}\mathrm C_{4}\times\!^{6}\mathrm C_{6}=\!^{10}\mathrm C_{6}\times\!^{4}\mathrm C_{4}$). Does this have a name? I've heard of [Pascal's Rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_rule) but I believe that's something quite different.

Comment: How about "Symmetry of Pascal's triangle"?

Comment: I've always heard it referred to as the symmetry of the binomial coefficients (at any rate, mathematicians will understand you if you use this phrase).

Comment: "Poincare duality for the n-dimensional torus" (just kidding)

Comment: ProofWiki calls this *symmetry rule*: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Symmetry_Rule_for_Binomial_Coefficients